# Facebook login in java application and get basic Info of User

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, servlets

I am trying to implement facebook login in my java application. Till now on button click i have called the servlet where it according to client id and secret key generate code and redirect it to the redirect uri. I have registered my test app on facebook developer console. 
Problem is that code is generating perfectly but access token is not getting generated through which I will get the basic Info. I have tried many codes. One of them is below.
**CLIENT SIDE**

```
google.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
  {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

        String fbURL = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=CLIENTID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT  URL &scope=email&scope=user_friends";
          Window.open(fbURL,"_blank","");


    }
});
```

**SERVLET**

```
 public userInfoServlet() {
    super();

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String rid = request.getParameter("request_ids");
        if (rid != null) {
            response.sendRedirect("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
                    + clientID + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectURI);
        } else {
            // Get code
            String code = request.getParameter("code");
            if (code != null) {

                // Format parameters
                URL url = new URL(
                        "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
                                + clientID + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectURI
                                + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret
                                + "&code=" + code);

                // request for Access Token
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                String line, outputString = "";
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    outputString += line;
                }
                out.println(outputString);

                // extract access token from response
                String accessToken = null;
                if(outputString.indexOf("access_token")!=-1) {
                    accessToken = outputString.substring(13,outputString.indexOf("&"));
                }

                // request for user info
                url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="
                        + accessToken);
                out.println(url);
                URLConnection conn1 = url.openConnection();
                outputString = "";
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        conn1.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    outputString += line;
                }
                reader.close();
                out.println(outputString);

                // convert response JSON to Pojo class
              FaceBookPojo fbp = new Gson().fromJson(outputString,
                       FaceBookPojo.class);
                out.println(fbp);
                                }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I am not getting what exactly the problem in generating the access token. Any help would be appreciable.

[tried this code also but the problem is same](http://javapapers.com/java/java-facebook-login-with-oauth-authentication/)

Comment: Is the accessToken value null or what?

Comment: its not printing even

Comment: I tried to print it through printwriter object on servlet. but only the code get print. no idea what is the matter

Comment: do System.out.println(accessToken); after its value is assigned, check the value in the console

Comment: but how will the code get generated on development mode? till now I was trying by hosting it.

Comment: Haven't you tested your code in local first? Try running your code in local & check the value of accessToken. Check the outputString value check if it is getting substringed right

Comment: Sir sorry for the confusion then what should be my redirect uri on developer console?

Comment: Just replace your hosting server address with localhost:portNum. Or if you want to check on your hosting server add logs in the code, redeploy & check the server logs.

Comment: Ok i  will jst try it too.

Comment: Still nothing printed on console and received connection refused message

Comment: You need to debug your code thoroughly check out the links http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16162_01/user.1112/e17455/run_debug_java.htm#OJDUG2059  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: You should probably rely on the official [Facebook Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android) instead of hacking these requests yourself.

Answer (score 0):

there is multiple scope parameters in your req. It should be only one.

Try this,

google.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
  {

```
@Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    String fbURL = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=CLIENTID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT  URL &scope=email,user_friends";
      Window.open(fbURL,"_blank","");
    }
});
```

It should works.